# SpringMVC Resources Path Changes When using Href Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-webcam-plugin

I have a Spring MVC application it uses `jquery.webcam.js` this file is located in a js folder in the resources directory on WAR `-resources -js,css.. - WEB-INF.` Thats the basic structure in the js directory there is a `jquery.webcam.js.`

When the form that uses `jquery.webcam.js` and other custom js files is fired its ok it finds all the js files. However on that form i click a button and i am then posted to another page, on this page i have a hyper link that has a url of `"getData/${id}.htm".` When i click on the hlink i am taken to the controller which has a mapping for this url:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="getData/{id}.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

In the controller a select is preformed from the database and an object is returned to the previous page (first form - that uses the jquery.webcam.js). When i am returned to that page i am getting in firebug a `404 error for the jquery.webcam.js` file.

Upon further inspection the url for the location of my resources has changed from   `http://localhost:8080/myApp/jquery.webcam.js` to `http://localhost:8080/myApp/getData/jquery.webcam.js`

Why has getData now became part of the resources url and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script files should be loaded like below..

If your `js folder` is under resource folder.

`<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.webcam.js"></script>`

Comment: just asking did you miss out the resources directory i had to use <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/jquery.webcam.js"></script> for it ot work. Also is it the same for css files?

Comment: yes ofcourse , in your case mentioning resource may be required. Normally it is not required if you folders are in webcontent.

Comment: i am also getting the issue happening again hope you dont mind looking at this for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416447/springmvc-http-status-405-request-method-post-not-supported?noredirect=1#comment21799926_15416447